# How to read Below Json data key and value individual?

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, json

{
"responsecode": 1,
"status": true,
"data": [
{
"id": "1",
"name": "Aircel",
"category": "Prepaid"
},
{
"id": "11",
"name": "Airtel",
"category": "Prepaid"
}
],
"message": "Operator List Fetched"
}

Comment: `const { data, status, message } =  response;`

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try and add some more details before you ask your question.